# PHP MySQL trouble

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If  I run this code , the value in the SQL base is  added 5x.

Code:

```
function token($u) {
    include('../config.php');
    $token=md5(rand()+$u);
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $tokenQuery = 'INSERT INTO '.$prefix.'tokens(`token`, `user`, `date`) VALUES ("'.$token.'","'.$u.'","'.$date.'")';
    $mysqli->query($tokenQuery);
}

token ('filips');
```

See how it look my SQL base

[image]

My config is:

```
$host = 'my server';
$user = 'my username';
$pass = 'my password';
$data = 'pn_16734995_filipcms_demo';
$prefix = 'fc_';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass, $data); 
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'" );

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Server not working: (" . $mysqli->connect_errnor. ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Comment: What's in your config file? Just database connection stuff?

Comment: Have you called your function in a loop?

Comment: the function is being called 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your code will make the INSERT statement happen 5 times. However, if you `echo "function called";` inside of your function, you can see if the function is being called 5 times, then you can figure out where up the line your function is being called 5 times.

Comment: I know, but have you tried the `echo "function called";` inside your function? Somewhere else you may be calling the function 5 times. The function itself doesn't INSERT 5 times, but if you are calling the function 5 times then you would get the same result.

Comment: I find out that is correct token just the first one , which are witten in the base

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to include the whole file just pass $mysqli as a parameter or put it in a global scope;

```
function token($u,$mysqli) {
}
```

OR

```
function token($u) {
global $mysqli;
}
```